# Namecheap domain not forwarding to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, namecheap

I have two [AWS buckets](http://prntscr.com/i4ia45)

The www one hosts a static website and the @ one redirects to the www one.

My namecheap's domain Advanced DNS settings are configured like [this](http://prntscr.com/i4iana)

I've waited about 12 hours, but when I go to my Namecheap domain, I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I've deleted all of the original CNAME & A records, did I make a mistake doing this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be working fine - perhaps you've got the old address cached in your environment.

Comment: Oh you're right it seems to work fine on my phone.. I had no idea! I'll try clearing my cache thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly now thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As @stdunbar suggested:

> It seems to be working fine - perhaps you've got the old address
>   cached in your environment.

I cleared my cache and it now works without any problems!